# -bash command not found

Tags: mysql, macos, unix, homebrew

I am new to Mac and was following a video and typed `export PATH="$HOME/opt/git/bin:$PATH"` I believe this messed up my path and I am not able to install MySQL now.  When I tried to install homebrew I get `-bash: homebrew: command not found.`

Comment: I know I hate getting in a messed up bath...

Comment: Belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I tagged it mysql because I am trying to install mysql

Comment: @eggyal I'll try SuperUser or Ask Different.  I have not tried those before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for homebrew is `brew`, not `homebrew`.

You can reset your path by restarting your shell. If you changed it in your ~/.bash_profile, edit it with TextEdit or similar first to remove the offending line, and restart the shell.

Comment: To reset your path, you just need to close out of the Terminal.app window and then create a new window. The path is not saved between sessions.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it correctly? Try running `/usr/local/bin/brew`. If it give you `No such file or directory` or something similar, then try installing homebrew again.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Terminal.app and relaunch; environment variables set with `export` should not persist across launches.

(You may need to close windows explicitly in case Lion's automatic window restoration interferes.)

Answer (score 0):

This could fix your problem, copy and paste the following into your terminal window and press enter:

```
echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

and then:

```
source ~/.profile
```